# check whether each value in json array are present in other json file

Tags: c++, arrays, json, jsoncpp

I have a json array

```
"requiredOnCreate": [
"Destination",
"EventTypes",
"Protocol"
 ]
```

I want to check whether all values present in this json array are present in this json file as keys (other json file)

```
{"Destination":"100.10.8.8",
"EventTypes":"ResourceUpdated",
"Protocol":"Redfish"}
```

I tried with many possibilities, but I can check each key at single time.
I want to write condition, if all values in json array are present in this json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through the first array, and check if there's an appropriate value in the second object.

Maintain a counter, and when the number of elements in the first array equals the number of found elements in the second object, all values from the first are in the second. Something like this (untested):

```
bool all_found = false;
int n = 0;
for (Json::Value::iterator i = required.begin(); i != required.end(); ++i) {
    if (!other[*i].isNull())
       ++n;
}

if (n == required.size())
    all_found = true;
```